# Bash Script how to monitor a process based on time ......restart if doesnt respond in 2 min

Tags: bash

I have created a bash script to monitor Symantec command line scan services, This is a part of the script later on I am sending email of log file I have created,a cron job to send email in every two hours.

Now my problem is that sometimes ssecls script does not respond and it stucks. How to implement a time check for each 4 servers below so that if ssecls does not respond then Symantec services will be restarted. I have created another script to restart services.

My only problem is , how to check if the below process is not responding or hang ....2 mins of interval.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Symatec Scan Command Line Scanner Options

cd /opt/SYMCScan/ssecls/
echo "Testing servera1 Scan Engine" `./ssecls /home/symtec/ -server Server1 -mode scan -verbose -details -timing -recurse -onerror leave -log /home/symtec/work/ssecls_log_serveraavr01`

echo "Testing server02 Scan Engine" `./ssecls /home/symtec/ -server Server2 -mode scan -verbose -details -timing -recurse -onerror leave -log /home/symtec/work/ssecls_log_serverdavr01`

echo "Testing server03 Scan Engine" `./ssecls /home/symtec/ -server  Server3 -mode scan -verbose -details -timing -recurse -onerror leave -log /home/symtec/work/ssecls_log_server1avr01`

echo "Testing server04 Scan Engine" `./ssecls /home/symtec/ -server Server4 -mode scan -verbose -details -timing -recurse -onerror leave -log /home/symtec/work/ssecls_log_server4avr01`
```

Answer (score 1):

`timeout` was written for just such a use.

```
timeout 120 ./ssecls ...
```

You can even configure it to send a signal other than kill, and to kill it some time after that.
Because the back ticks are executed before the command line, you'll need to put the `timeout` inside them.

To restart, you'll want a loop.

```
until timeout 120 ./ssecls ...; do
    echo Timed out, restarting.
done
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for the reply , but timeout: command not found. I dont have root access and it's redhat linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

> timeout: command not found.

You can achieve something similar with this bash function:

```
timeout()
{
    time=$1; shift
    "$@"& pid=$!
    ( sleep $time; kill $! )&
    wait $pid && kill $!
}
```

Call this function just as described in Kevin's answer.